# Event listener for host connections/disconnections RouterOS MikroTik

Tags: router, vpn, mikrotik-routeros

I have a MikroTik router running RouterOS. I’d like to keep a database full of documents of currently connected/previously connected hosts. Instead of probing the router for currently connected hosts at an interval of ‘x’, I’d like to just write a script to listen for an event where a host connects/disconnects & have the router provide the data for currently connected hosts then.

Is this something easily done, where there is such an event already integrated into the router? If not, do you have any recommendations of research/steps I should take to create such a solution?

Thank you very much, Austin

Answer (score 1):

The Mikrotik API provides this; you connect to the API and listen for particular events using the "listen" command. You will get notified automatically.

https://wiki.mikrotik.com/wiki/Manual:API#.2Fuser.2Factive.2Flisten